# Python Pandas-read-datetime when timepate ends with 00:00:00.000 eg: '05NOV2019:00:00:00.000'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am reading a pipe delimited datetime field into python pandas all items are formatted thus `05NOV2019:00:00:00.000`

On import and I do a df.info() the field is of `dtype: object`

I have tried to change the dtype using `pd.to_datetime()` Result:

> ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '05NOV2019:00:00:00.000')

also - tried taking a slice of the string too. Result told me I couldn't do that to a float? - tells me its an dtype 'object'

Then I grabbed at a few other straws not knowing what I am doing.

Can anyone put me on the right track to get a datetime such as: 05NOV2019:00:00:00

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

just set the [parsing directive](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) explicitly:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(["05NOV2019:00:00:00.000"])

pd.to_datetime(s, format="%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f")
0   2019-11-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you solution - will try it out  Looks similar to something that I previously tried   but as I stated, I was only bumbling and stumbing - datetime Grrrrrr!!

Comment: @TechnoGronk you'll get the hang of it eventually ;-) Many times, pd.to_datetime does a good job inferring the format, but it's always a good idea to double-check, and in cases like this, just tell the function what to do.